# Python: Return value of a specific index in array using another array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

Say I have two arrays A and b where b represents the index of a specific element in A.

```
   A = [1,7,9,1,0,0,0]
   b = [2,4,5]
```

How can I print out every value that b refers to?
For example I want the first element of b to print out 7?

Comment: Use: `c = [A[x-1] for x in b]`, however you might want to rethink your 1-based indices.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
for i in b:
    print(a[i - 1])
```

This will use the element of b as an index for a to retrieve that specific element. Notice how i did `i - 1`. This is because Since you want the `2` of `b` to correlate to the `7` in `a`, which normally has an index of `1`. This is why we should do `i - 1` so the index is shifted.

I hope this helped! Let me know if you need any more details or clarification :)